# Create Hotspot Without WPA or Password

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, hotspot, netsh, wpa2

Setting up a network for my area to provide free WIFI, but there doesn't seem to be a way to create a hotspot without WPA2 even using the netsh commands with empty password like I see repeated 1000 times.

Does Windows really provide you no option to create an open WIFI? I created one using a bridged USB WIFI adapter via a Linux Virtualbox but I want to just do it on windows without having to run a Virtual Machine all the time.

Comment: Did you use the search functionality?

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows does not allow open (no security) Hotspot wireless.

You need a router that supports open wireless.

Or, as you note, a VM with an OS that supports open wireless. Be aware that using a VM for open wireless can still compromise your machine.